# How do you exchange private data with Pimpl without exposing your internals?

Tags: c++, pimpl-idiom

If you have an object B that needs  a copy of a private member of an object A, and the private member is hidden by a Pimpl, how do you make it happen without exposing your internals?
// Foo.h

```
class Foo
{
private :
  struct impl ;
  impl * pimpl ;
};

// Foo.cpp
struct impl { std::string data; }

//main.cpp
Foo A;
Foo B;
// I want A::pimpl->data copied to B::pimpl->data and I don't want std::string exposed in my Foo header.
```

Comment: Write a member function to do the copy.

Comment: I can't see how without exposing std::string in the Foo header.

Comment: lol - question sounds dirty... just me? oh well.

Comment: @Dennis: Naughty, Naughty! ;)

Comment: @joey: you mean, you want your clients to access the string without knowing it's a string?

Comment: @joey: see my answer for a solution that avoids exposing `std::string` in the `Foo` header file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
// header
class Foo
{
    public:
       void Copy( const Foo & );
    private :
       struct impl ;
       impl * pimpl ;

};

//cpp file
struct impl {std::string data; }

void Foo::Copy( const Foo & f ) {
      pimpl->data = f.pimpl->data;
}
```

Comment: How can I acess pimpl in f since it's private ?

Comment: @joey You need to  re-read your C++ text book. Access control in C++ is per class, not per class instance.

Comment: @joey_89: It's a member function. You can access private data.

Answer (score 3):

`Foo` needs to implement a constructor, a copy constructor, a destructor and an assignment operator, doing the "right thing" - allowing you to do e.g. 'A = B;'

```
// Foo.h
struct FooImpl;
class Foo
{
  Foo(Foo const &);
  Foo();
  ~Foo();
  Foo & operator=(Foo const & RHS);
private:
  FooImpl * pimpl;
};

// Foo.cpp
struct FooImpl {std::string data; }

Foo & Foo::operator=(Foo const & RHS) {
  *pimpl = *RHS.pimpl;
  return *this;
}
Foo::Foo(Foo const & V) {
  pimpl = new FooImpl(*V.pimpl);
}

Foo::Foo() {
  pimpl = new FooImpl;
}

Foo::~Foo() {
  delete pimpl;
}
```

Now you can safely do:

```
Foo A;
Foo B;
A = B;
```

Comment: I don't want to copy all the object, only a private member.

Comment: if you speak on doing the right thing, then please use a smart pointer rather than manual clean-up :)

Comment: @joey_89: Then use the method unapersson describes

Comment: @Matthieu M.: Yep, but then I'd change his class instead of explaining what's lacking.

Comment: you would, but you would also instill good practice. I personally think it's worth it :) But to each its own! (And belated congratulations for the 20k mark)

Answer (score 0):

Other issues aside (copy constructor, ec.), if you want to access `impl::data` without imposing the `<string>` header to all your clients, you can do something like the following:

```
// Foo.h
class FooUtil;
class Foo
{
friend class FooUtil;
private :
  struct impl ;
  impl * pimpl ;
};

// FooUtil.h
#include <string>
class FooUtil
{
public:
    static std::string data_of(const Foo&);
};

// Foo.cpp
struct impl { std::string data; }
std::string FooUtil::data_of(const Foo& foo)
{
    return foo.impl->data;
}

//main.cpp
Foo A;
Foo B;
```

This is a hack-ish work-around for having a `std::string Foo::data() const` member function.  The idea is that you can have the `<string>` header included by only the clients who need it.

**Disclaimer**: I *really* don't like this approach.  It's very inelegant and is unlikely to really increase compile times.  Some compilers cache (or pre-compile) standard library headers so as to help people avoid this kind of mess.